# Audit: what did I do wrong?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, disputed-review-audits

I'm reviewing close votes, and I voted to close an off-topic question, but it turns out that this was a test and that I'd failed. The thing is, I think I did the right thing because the question is totally off topic.

The question is: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6199454

The topic is setting environment variables in osx. Why did I fail the audit?

Comment: You did nothing wrong. Soon, enough of us will have downvoted and/or voted to close that question to ensure it will not be used as an audit again.

Comment: [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773)

Comment: Audits are based on decisions made on the site. Not all of these are good. So there's some audits that will end up just being wrong.

Comment: Closing this because Community keeps bumping it... pointlessly. The question leading to the failed audit has been closed and deleted, so it won't ever trip up anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this as being particularly off-topic; if you're running Apache on OSX, you're either using it as a development tool ([which are on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) or you're crazy.

So let's assume good faith, and... Good mental health.

**In response to comments:** we're not talking about a rubber duck or a web browser. If you're running Apache on your local machine, you're probably using it to develop web apps. Sure, you *could* be doing something else with it, just like you *could* be using Visual Studio to write your pulp romance novel - but you're not. There are thousands of Apache, LAMP and WAMP configuration questions already on SO - if you're serious about arguing that these should be driven away, be honest about it and go start a discussion that proposes just that; otherwise, you got the audit wrong - learn from it and move on.

Comment: Good faith does not make good audits. Just saying.

Comment: Nah, it doesn't become 'on topic' just because the end of the process produces something that may one day be used for development. Besides, Apache isn't often used in a development environment -- it's too heavy for that, it's much more common to find it in a production setting -- so it's probable that even though they OP is using apache they're not using it for development (the point here is that we don't know and can't assume). Configuring an OS's environment variables is off topic, no matter what its for in the end.

Comment: Are you joking, @EngineerDollery? Tons of people use Apache for dev work. I *highly* doubt he's running a production server on OSX.

Comment: No, he's probably just messing around with tech he doesn't understand. But, with all due respect -- I spend my life drifting across the planet helping out one software development project after another, and I've done this full-time for nearly 30 years now, so I have some experience of this: apache is rarely used in dev rigs. The vast majority of software is in java, and apache usually isn't needed for anything being done in java. Other software is mainly embedded (phones, washing machines, aircraft) and apache isn't too useful there either.

Comment: For the sake of argument: My rubber ducky is my #1 most important development tool. I don't ask questions about it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: But seriously, it's not a good sign if we have to make assumptions about the OP's motivation or circumstances (or mental health, for that matter) in order to figure out whether the question is on topic.

Comment: You're making an ass out of u and that guy.  If I'm asking a question about installing Chrome on my desktop you wouldn't assume I'm going to be developing plugins for it, you'd kick me over to SU.  Nope.  Hang your head in shame.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I have spent an equal amount of time in this industry, and likely in at least as many places, and I see (and recommend) Apache for dev environments ALL THE TIME.

Comment: @EngineerDollery If you're a consultant with a Java background (and I'm assuming that from looking at your profile) then there's a fairly big chance you mostly see Java projects. That doesn't mean the vast majority of software is Java. It's like a professional football (soccer) player saying most people kick their ball while ignoring the fact that basketball is a thing.

Comment: What I see really often is people downvoting without even commenting and that review is one example: 6 downvotes and not even a comment explaining why or asking for more information to see if really is an off-topic or not

Comment: Why even question whether apache is a development tool or not? The question is not about apache, it's a question about service daemons & their environment variables. It could have used "counterstrike server deamon" instead and neither question nor answer would be different.

Comment: @zapl -- exactly my point. The question wasn't about programming.

Comment: @ivarni -- no, industry statistics say that java is the most popular - check it out: http://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/software/top-10-programming-languages

Comment: @TML -- really? Wow. Have you considered going on a training course covering more modern development practices? My company runs one if you'd like a recommendation.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I appreciate the offer, but if it's not broke, I don't fix it. I also fail to see how a gap of ~2% validates your assertion that "the vast majority of software is in java"; I think "Java edges out C by a slim margin" is a more accurate encapsulation.

Comment: @EngineerDollery You have a strange definition of the words "vast majority". I'm sorry but if you can look at that graph and say "the vast majority of software is in java" I'm not sure there's much hope.

Comment: Guess Community♦ didn't think +18/-18 was [enough attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/276521/timeline) :P

Comment: Yeah, I haven't seen any votes on this in 5 years @CertainPerformance - gotta grease the wheels a bit!